# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: not called for iOS5 after dismissing from modal

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, orientation

My main UIViewController overrides `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to adapt the background view for the correct orientation. This works fine when staying within the view.

But in my app, the result of some user actions can lead to presenting another "daughter" UIViewController. When the user is done with that daughter UIViewController, she normally returns to the main view controller. My code calls `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to do so.

The issue occurs when the user changes the iPad orientation while the daughter UIViewController is on screen. Then, the main UIViewController will never see any call to `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and its background view will be incorrect.

This setup works fine in iOS 4: the iOS 4 implementation of `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` calls `UIWindow`'s `_setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:` which calls `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` for the switched in `UIViewController`.

Apparently , this behavior changed for iOS 5.

How am I expected to implemented orientation changes while my view is off screen under iOS5? Am I supposed to query the current orientation in `viewWillAppear:` for example? I did so, and it works around the issue just fine, but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Try to handle interface change via Notification Center like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

And do interface-related stuff in "orientationChanged" method

Comment: Good tips. I spend one hour to figure out why willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration not working in iOS5, but in iOS6 it works.

Comment: This does not help if things need to be done before the rotation has happened.